# Error when loading /home/user_name/.profile

Tags: linux, terminal, etc

I was trying to install awesomeWM and after logging out i saw this message.

```
Error when loading /home/user_name/.profile
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

Comment: That message occurred while you were logging *out*? Perhaps you can share the relevant lines from the `.profile`?

Answer (score -1):

try adding

```
export TERM=xterm
```

to `/etc/profile`

Comment: Changing system-wide files for a user-specific issue is not a good idea.